# Converting OpenStreetMap (OSM) file to shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, linux

I am trying to convert an ".osm" file to a shapefile. I want to display roads mainly.

I am using qgis (on Debian Linux) ..

EDIT (as recommended):
O.k, here is the problem ... I want to create a shapefile for an Amateur Radio application ... the current shapefiles they have really sucks big time ... so I downloaded qGis (which I regret wasting data on) and it is one BIG confusing hole of misery ...

Eventually after reading 2 hours of uninformative badly written examples on the net I finally figured out myself how to get OpenStreetMaps loaded into bloatware qGis ...

I select the area I wanted to work with ... after freezing up 4 times I eventually got evilware qGis NOT to break anything and download the info ... now I have an .osm file ... there is only one export option, something called epx? ... there is no option to save or export it as a shapefile ...

I hope that gives more clarity ...

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to ask a question. As it stands it is too broad and vague.

Comment: It should not really be difficult at all but all OSM files are not alike. Put a sample of your data available or write a query for downloading data from some OSM service or detailed instructions for downloading data with QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, is to add this osm file to qgis.

[image]

You will be asked which layer to add.

[image]

Once the layer is added, you can then export it to shape file

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility to download OSM data directly as shapefiles via http://download.geofabrik.de/